# LocalJumpError: no block given

Tags: ruby, rspec

I keep getting an error while running a rspec file:

```
Failures:                                                                                                                                  

  1) Book title should capitalize the first letter                                                                                         
     Failure/Error: @book.title("inferno")                                                                                                 
     LocalJumpError:                                                                                                                       
       no block given (yield)                                                                                                              
     # ./08_book_titles.rb:7:in `title'
```

here is the book_title.rb

```
class :: Book

  attr_accessor :some_title

def title(some_title)
little_words = %w(of and for the over under an a but or nor yet so at around by after along from on to with without)
  some_title = yield
  some_title.split.each_with_index.map{|x, index| little_words.include?(x) && index > 0 ? x : x.capitalize }.join(" ")
end #def

end
```

and here is the rspec file (or at least the first spec):

```
require_relative '08_book_titles'

describe Book do

  before do
    @book = Book.new
  end

  describe 'title' do
    it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
      @book.title("inferno")
      @book.title.should == "Inferno"
    end
end
```

I have included the yield in the method, and there IS a block in the spec...so I don't understand why its not calling that block. I have tried everything I could think of from calling it directly on the map (instead of using a variable it is assigned to) to calling it separately on its own THEN using it on map, to trying to pass it in as the argument of title in the method...to what you see now. I have also read through a ton of threads. What am I not seeing?

I see that future exercises will also be running specs on custom classes so I would also love some tips (or links) on things I need to know or look out for while testing custom classes with rspec.  Thanks!

UPDATED

So i have changed my book_title.rb to look like this:

```
  class :: Book

  def title
little_words = %w(of and for the over under an a but or nor yet so at around by after along from on to with without)
    self.split.each_with_index.map{|x, index| little_words.include?(x) && index > 0 ? x : x.capitalize }.join(" ")
end #def

end
```

and because I, probably incorrectly, edited the specs- I reverted them back to this:

```
require '08_book_titles'

describe Book do

  before do
    @book = Book.new
  end

  describe 'title' do
    it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
      @book.title = "inferno"
      @book.title.should == "Inferno"
    end
end
```

and the error I now get is this:

```
Failure/Error: @book.title = "inferno"                                                                                                
     NoMethodError:                                                                                                                        
       undefined method `title=' for #<Book:0x007f292a06c6b0>                                                                              
     # ./08_book_titles_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you get another error, it's probably best to post the new error as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mis-using `yield` and no, there's no block in the spec.  If there was, the spec would look like...

```
  @book.title("inferno") do
    "inferno"
  end
```

See the block I added?  But you don't need a block and you shouldn't use `yield`

You seem to be thinking that you need `yield` to access the argument... you don't.  Your `title` method should just use the passed argument directly...

```
def title(new_title)
little_words = %w(of and for the over under an a but or nor yet so at around by after along from on to with without)
  @some_title = new_title.split.each_with_index.map{|x, index| little_words.include?(x) && index > 0 ? x : x.capitalize }.join(" ")
end #def
```

Finally, your test is actually calling the `title` method twice, when you should only call it once and use the attr_accessor method to test the result.

```
it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
  @book.title("inferno")
  @book.some_title.should == "Inferno"
end
```

Comment: Oh wow! I totally got stuck in thinking I needed yield as the last few exercises required (and my brain is fried from all this Ruby lol). To think I have wasted at least 1-2 hours trying to get a yield I didn't need to work. Sigh. I am confused as to what you mean about the `title` method being called twice, it seems the first call is defining the argument and the next is testing it. How would that be recreated only using the attr_accessor? I didn't write the spec file btw, it was provided as part of a exercise - I'd just like to know why this is wrong and a better way to do it:)

Comment: I changed the title so that people who are having a Local Jump Error who actually DO have a block (unlike me), don't waste their time ;)

Comment: There's only one method `title`   When you run it as `@book.title('inferno')` you are setting the @some_title instance value.  When you run it  in `@book.title.should...` you're going to get an error that `new_title` wasn't passed.

When you said `attr_accessor some_title` you created two methods, an accessor to retrieve the value `some_title` and a setter to set the value `some_title=`  

The `some_title` method is how you retrieve the value.

You COULD do `@book.some_title('inferno').should == "Inferno"` ... that's legitimate but then you don't need the "defining the argument"

Comment: That's helpful, I am still pretty new to this and when/how to define attr_accessor, initializing etc ... are still pretty fuzzy to me - so I need to bone up on that for sure. Your above answer makes sense to me for the most part.  I have updated my code as I am still getting an error :(

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your EDIT, you can't do `self.split` since self is a Book object, not a string.

You could modify your `title` method so that it's a setter method... make it `title=` instead of `title`

```
  def title=(new_title)
little_words = %w(of and for the over under an a but or nor yet so at around by after along from on to with without)
    @title = new_title.split.each_with_index.map{|x, index| little_words.include?(x) && index > 0 ? x : x.capitalize }.join(" ")
end #def
```

that gives you the "title=" method that your tests say is missing.  And you can create a getter method...

```
def title
  @title
end
```

And now your tests (as you've written them) should work fine.